# How to render comments at the top and the comment form at the bottom?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, comments

I'm trying to display the comments on a node at the top of the page. I've edited `node.tpl.php` in my theme to be:

```
<article id="article-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print $unpublished; ?>
  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if(!empty($user_picture) || $title || (!empty($submitted) && $display_submitted)): ?>
    <header class="clearfix<?php $user_picture ? print ' with-picture' : ''; ?>">

      <?php print $user_picture; ?>

      <?php if ($title): ?>
        <h1<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
          <?php if ($page): ?>
            <?php print $title; ?>
          <?php elseif (!$page): ?>
            <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php print $title; ?></a>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </h1>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
        <div class="submitted">
        <?php 
            //By:   Mike Ghen 
            //Date: 5/21/2012
            //Description: This Modifies the submitted user and date info.
            //             Code from: http://drupal.org/node/1072640
            if ($submitted) { 
                echo "Submitted on " . date( "F j, Y",$node->created);  
            } 
        ?>      
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

    </header>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <div<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
  <?php
    hide($content['comments']);
    hide($content['links']);
    print render($content);
  ?>
  </div>

  <?php if ($links = render($content['links'])): ?>
  <?php endif; ?>



</article>
```

I moved `<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>` to the top of the page but, it makes the form to fill out a comment appear at the top of the page as well. Is there a way to render the comments at the top and the comment form at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

you attack this line in file :

```
<?php
    // Remove the "Add new comment" link on the teaser page or if the comment
    // form is being displayed on the same page.
    if ($teaser || !empty($content['comments']['comment_form'])) {
      unset($content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);
      unset($content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-comments']);
            unset($content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment_forbidden']);
    }
    // Only display the wrapper div if there are links.
    $links = render($content['links']);
    if ($links):
  ?>
    <div class="link-wrapper">
      <?php 
      hide($content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-comments']);
      print $links; 
      ?>       
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are editing a node template , in this situation you are not able to change an element itself , but you can go to comments module , there you can find a template file inside which generates the comment output , copy it to your theme folder/templates then modify it there and changes will be applied.
An easier solution could gain by using Panels and page manager . it will take you just some mouse clicks.